# ASP: CommandArgument

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vbscript

I am trying to pass values within a repeater binding them to a button and pass them from this form to another form. When i compile this it gives me an error indicating

`System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Button within Repeater Code in form1.aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="" CommandName= "TEST"  CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Parking_ID") + "," + Eval("Parking_Name") %>' />
```

in form1.aspx.vb Repeater_ItemCommand Function:

```
 Protected Sub repeater1_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles repeater1.ItemCommand
        If (e.CommandName = "TEST") Then
            Dim commandArgsAccept As String() = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(New Char() {","c})
            Dim value As Int32 = commandArgsAccept(0).ToString
            Dim value1 As String = commandArgsAccept(1).ToString

            Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?Parking_ID=" & value, True)
            Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?Parking_Name=" & value1, True)


            Session("field4") = value
            Session("field6") = value1


        End If






    End Sub
```

Any solution for this problem? 
Regards.

Comment: Good, I am giving same idea in previous answer, but I was asssuming you only need Parking_name Field.

Comment: @ Muhammad Akhtar u need 23 to got magic 10,000. best of luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="" CommandName= "TEST"  CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Parking_ID").ToString() +","+ Eval("Parking_Name").ToString() %>'/>


 Protected Sub repeater1_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles repeater1.ItemCommand
        If (e.CommandName = "TEST") Then
            Dim commandArgsAccept As String() = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(",")
            Dim value As Int32 = commandArgsAccept(0).ToString
            Dim value1 As String = commandArgsAccept(1).ToString




            Session("field4") = value
            Session("field6") = value1

            Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?Parking_ID=" & value & "&Parking_Name=" & value1, True)


        End If
```

Comment: That `.ToString()` part on `Eval()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya: `Parking_ID` is passed but `Parking_Name` is not passed.

Comment: True, but in this `ToString()` case it's called implicitly.

Comment: @Humam Shbib : r u fetching it from Session ?

Comment: @Govind KamalaPrakash Malviya: YES on form2.aspx.vb                `Dim field4 As String = Request.QueryString("Parking_ID")`
`Dim field6 As String = Request.QueryString("Parking_Name")`

Answer (score 0):

Put the name of the key field of the database in a public variable, so you do not syntax error

```
public string registerKey = "myId";

protected void btnCancel_Command (object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // With the CommandEventArgs you get the parameters sent
    UpdatePanel2.Update ();
}

<asp: Button ID = "btnCancel" Text = "Cancel" CommandName = "CancelDeposit" OnCommand = "btnCancel_Command" runat = "server" CommandArgument = '<% # DataBinder.GetPropertyValue (Container.DataItem, registerKey)%> ">
```